# is the documentation for oracle-sql and mysql the same with respect to the definitions, syntaxes and rules?

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g

I recently started exploring sql basics in oracle to help myself to work on a migration project where project is subject to migrate from Oracle platform to a different one; while trying to google for a concept, say for instance, on-delete and on-update clauses and actions, the result has web-links for mysql and oralce-sql; what concerns me here is whether to consider mysql and oracle documentation for interpretation, and sometimes mysql documentation got a better explanation and hence I fell into dilemma.

would anyone please comment on my concern.

Thank you for giving your valuable time and knowledge.

Comment: No, Oracle RDBMS and MySQL RDBMS are different. To some degree they both support the ANSI SQL standard and to some degree they each (as do all other RDBMS) differ from the ANSI standard and each other. You can look up some documentation find it works in most RDBMS and then you can look up other documentation and no database will do it with the same syntax. If you are working in one RDBMS then use the documentation for that RDBMS - if the documentation is confusing then read other documentation until you can understand the first documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle <> MySQL.

Although some things work the same way and share the same syntax, you can't rely on one database's documentation presuming that it can be applied to another.

Also, maybe you were mislead by the fact that Oracle *owns* MySQL so both databases' documentation links look similar (docs.oracle.com/...).

Therefore, similar: yes, but same: no.